# What is the name for evoking an answer that's a trick on the responder?

Tags: terminology

Mister Mxyzptlk was a trickster who tormented Superman. Although the rules eventually changed, the only way that Superman could send Mister Mxyzptlk back to the fifth dimension was to trick him into saying his name (Mxyzptlk) backwards (Kltpzyxm - "kel-tip-zix-um"). Superman was usually successful. Tricking someone into saying something inadvertently is a common strategy of several childhood jokes. "What are the first letters of the words Iggy's cat uses paper?" "Uh, I, c, u, p." "No, you don't!" A recent question on ELU used a variation on the scheme and was promptly sent into purgatory. Is there a name for this kind of verbal trick?

Answer (score 2):

How about **trick question**? From Cambridge:

> **[trick question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trick-question)**: a question that makes you believe you should answer it in a particular way, when the real question is hidden or there is no right answer

If a **trick question** is not a question that "evokes an answer that's a trick on the responder," I don't know what would be.

Answer (score -1):

to **cajole**. [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cajole)

> influence by gentle urging, caressing, flattering or use of insincere language

From French words meaning "to chatter like a jaybird" and "to lure into a cage.

As in:

> Superman cajoled ...

Comment: Great word. But not what OP is asking about.